# R calculate means by criteria

Tags: r

Given the following dataset, I need a way of calculating the means of each sample by TERRITORY and populating the appropriate columns. Any suggestions for the best approach.

```
TERRITORY     SAMPLE_A   SAMPLE_B    SAMPLE_C    MEAN_A   MEAN_B    MEAN_C
    A                 21        34           23
    A                 23        23           54
    B                 34        67           23
    B                 35        76           65
    C                 45        34           65
    C                 87        34           45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do this, but if you want to stick to base R, use `aggregate`. If your data frame is `d` then the means can be calculated as

```
means <- aggregate(. ~ TERRITORY,  data = d, mean)
```

Then rename the columns containing means and merge with the original data frame

```
names(means) <- gsub("^SAMPLE_", "MEAN_", names(means))
merge(d, means)
```

Comment: +1 for `base`. This approach however returns a dataframe with one row for each unique value of territory. From the OP's question it seems like he wants the means in the original table, which can be achieved using a `?merge`.

Comment: Sure, I 'll update the answer to include the merging

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Here one approach using `plyr`. Note: I assume that `RE` in sample c is supposed to be a missing value? That is, an `NA`?

Anyway, try

```
 library(plyr)
 new.dat <- ddply(dat, .(territory), transform, 
        mean_a = mean(sample_a), mean_b= mean(sample_b), mean_c=mean(sample_c))
```

where `dat` is your data etc. You may need to adjust the column names and set `NA` options for `mean`. For instance, writing `mean(sample_x, na.rm=T)` will compute means for all non-missing values. Otherwise, `NA` will be returned.